# Why were BTC not accepted in the Humble Borderlands Bundle?

Tags: payment, merchants, zero-confirmation

AFAIK, so far, BTC has been accepted in every Humble Bundle since they started accepting them… instead they weren't an available option with the Borderlands bundle.

Is there an official, semi-official, or educatedly speculated reason?

[I asked](https://twitter.com/Lohoris/status/614548459606122497) but they didn't answer.

*No "we can't read their mind" answer: if they didn't state the reason, I really don't see why anyone knowledgable enough couldn't make an educated guess.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fraud.

> Estrella (Humble Bundle) Jun 23, 15:46
>
> Hi there,
>
> Thanks for writing in to Humble Bundle Support!
>
> Unfortunately, Bitcoin has been disabled for the Humble Borderlands
>   Bundle. The individual payment options made available for a given
>   bundle are determined when we finalize contracts with our development
>   partners. In this case, it was 2K Games' wish to only support PayPal,
>   and our native credit card processor, Stripe. I'm sorry for any
>   disappointment this may cause.
>
> In regards to the store, we've had to temporarily disable the Bitcoin
>   payment option due to a sharp increase in fraudulent payments in that
>   channel. While we do not have an ETA as to when the payment option
>   will return, we are planning on bringing it back and we are working
>   hard on getting things fixed as quickly as possible!
>
> Again, I'm sorry for the inconvenience here. If you have any other
>   questions or concerns, feel free to write us back!
>
> -Estrella Humble Bundle http://support.humblebundle.com/

[source](https://np.reddit.com/r/Bitcoin/comments/3avl4z/humble_bundle_doesnt_accept_bitcoin_anymore/csgh84b)

Comment: Oh, I'm surprised, I thought it was the bitcoin processor that ate the losses in case they reported a fraudulent transaction to be valid…

Comment: Given that a major design goal of Bitcoin is to be *much less* susceptible to fraudulent payments than credit cards, it would be interesting to know more specifically what kind of issues they are having.

Comment: @Lohoris That is surprising, but that's their officially stated reason.

Comment: Well, they accepted 0-confirmations transactions, so the issue is clearly that. But I'm really surprised they couldn't just add a few confirmations as requirement, instead of outright removing it.

Answer (score -1):

The cause is not literal fraud… They received tons of orders using Bitcoin from "Unauthorized Resellers" that buy tons of keys.

Comment: Is that based on speculation or do you have a source for that?

Comment: Hi, Yep I know someone doing it.. Here's what you get on humble bundle when you order via bitcoin.. "Invalid amount. Unfortunately, the minimum allowed purchase amount for Bitcoin is $2.50 due to recent abuse."